# How to add constraints after an addSubview so the subview resizes with the superview

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, cocoa, autolayout

I have a sample project which demonstrates the problem here

https://github.com/ericgorr/autolayout_with_addsubview.git

I have a view called CalcView which I want to programmatically add as a subview to a view on the main window for the app. When I resize my window, *I want CalcView to be resized*.

In windowDidLoad in MainWindowController, I add the subview by doing:

```
let calcViewController  = ELIZCalcView()
let calcView            = calcViewController.view

calcContentView?.addSubview( calcViewController.view )
```

I try to add the constraints by doing:

```
let bindings            = [ "calcView": calcView ]

let horizontalContraint:[AnyObject] = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat( "H:|[calcView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: bindings )
let verticalContraint:[AnyObject]   = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat( "V:|[calcView]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: bindings )

calcContentView?.addConstraints( horizontalContraint )
calcContentView?.addConstraints( verticalContraint )
```

Now, for someone who knows how to properly interpret that code, it is likely very apparent that it will not work. After I run my app, I cannot resize the window at all. Additionally, I see the following error message in the console:

```
2015-07-04 16:04:45.019 aocsCalc[5797:3526462] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints: (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000082440 V:|-(0)-[NSView:0x600000120f00]   (Names: '|':aocsCalc.ELIZHighlightView:0x608000120500 )>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x618000084100 h=--& v=&-- V:|-(-2)-[NSView:0x600000120f00]   (Names: '|':aocsCalc.ELIZHighlightView:0x608000120500 )>" )

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint  <NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000082440 V:|-(0)-[NSView:0x600000120f00]   (Names: '|':aocsCalc.ELIZHighlightView:0x608000120500 )>

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
```

If I remove the vertical constraint, the error message goes away and I can resize the window vertically.

So, what simple thing do I need to do so CalcView is resized along with the window?

Answer (score 18):

Before you add your calcView as subview try inserting this line of code:

```
calcView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

This should solve your problem.

By default on UIView/NSView this property is set to YES/true and it creates it's own set of constraints based on autoresizing mask. These auto-made constraints conflict with the ones you've created in code.

It clearly says so in the error description too. On lines 2 and 3 it shows you that there's 2 set of vertical constraints regarding one view - `NSView:0x600000120f00`, which appears to be your calcView.

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x618000082440 V:|-(0)-[NSView:0x600000120f00] 
<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x618000084100 h=--& v=&-- V:|-(-2)-[NSView:0x600000120f00]
```

They are both vertical. First one wants to snap view to the superview's top with no margin. The second one (created automatically) wants to snap it with a small margin, presumably taken from how it is layed out in Interface Builder.

**UPDATE**

Create a new Cocoa Application project and paste the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let view = NSView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(view)

    //Making it red just to see a little better. Ignore this two lines.
    view.wantsLayer = true
    view.layer?.backgroundColor = CGColorCreateGenericRGB(1, 0, 0, 1)
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    let views = ["view" : view]
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("|-[view]-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(0), metrics: nil, views: views))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-[view]-|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))

}
```

Newly created NSView is snapped to the View Controllers main view with standard margins (8 points, it's described as "-" in the visual format string) and is resizing with the main view (see pictures). A little tip - you don't have to specify the "H:" in the visual format, only "V:". It's horizontal by default.

This should give you a good idea of how adding constraints programmatically works. Code might not be optimal, I code in Obj-C and know very little Swift.

I've downloaded your project. Error probably lies somewhere in your complicated view hierarchy and xib manipulation. But that's a whole other story. Also be careful with scroll views, they are a bit tricky when it comes to autolayout, you can find a lot of coverage on that on SO. Happy coding :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: I'm don't have much experience with OS X development, but I think UIView and NSView act the same when it comes to constraints. [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSView/translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) say that NSView has that property. You must have typed it wrong or something.

Comment: Changing it from a function call to a property assignment got rid of the compile error, but the actual behavior I am seeing is a lot worse. The views are no longer positioned properly on the window at all. I have updated the git hub project with the change.

Comment: Your original question has been answered, so you should consider giving NKorotkov the credit. I've downloaded and run your updated project and can't really see what the problem is. You should be explicit about what you want to achieve but can't - probably in a separate question (+1 for posting sample projects by the way).

Comment: @ericgorr I've updated my answer. That should be enough to understand how to use autolayout with code.

Comment: Thank you. But, I am looking for the solution for the code I made available on github.

Comment: @ericgorr as Paul Patterson mentioned above original question has been answered, so you probably should create a new thread considering your sample project and what's not working properly. It's going to make it easier for other people who's looking for answers on similar problems.